# error with draw mpchart using sqlite dataset

Tags: java, android, sqlite, mpandroidchart

i use mpchart to draw chart for my sqlite database, but it runs with crash,
this is eclipse error log : (before crash, LogCat shows dataset)

> one or more of the Dataset Entry array longer than the x-values array
>   of this CharData object

**this is my "onProgressChanged" method code,that i think caused problem:**

```
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    tvX.setText("" + (mSeekBarX.getProgress() + 1));
    tvY.setText("" + (mSeekBarY.getProgress()));
    ArrayList<BarEntry> yVals3 = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();
    TimeListDatabaseHelper db = new TimeListDatabaseHelper(this);
    for (int i = 0; i < mSeekBarX.getProgress() + 1; i++) {
        Cursor c = db.getTimeRecordList();
        if (c != null && c.getCount() > 0) { 
            c.moveToFirst();
            for (int count = 0; count < c.getCount(); count++) {
               yVals3.add(new BarEntry(c.getInt(0), count));
               c.moveToNext();

            }
            c.close();
            for (Object obj1: yVals3) {
                Log.i("mSeekBarX1", obj1.toString());
            }
        }

        ArrayList<String> xVals = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < mSeekBarX.getProgress() + 1; i++) {
          xVals.add((int) yVals3.get(i).getVal() + "");
              }
         BarDataSet set1 = new BarDataSet(yVals3, "Data Set");
        set1.setColors(ColorTemplate.VORDIPLOM_COLORS);
        set1.setDrawValues(false);

        ArrayList<BarDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<BarDataSet>();
        dataSets.add(set1);

        BarData data = new BarData(xVals, dataSets);

        mChart.setData(data);
        mChart.invalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post a complete error stacktrace?

Comment: `yVals3.add(new BarEntry(c.getInt(0), count));` What is the value of the `count` variable? ie how many times  does this execute? Also check what values does this `c.getInt(0)` return.

Comment: count is for x values,i changed it to other value and nothing happened.and **c.getInt(0)** returnes database dataset

Comment: @vanekjar ,error stacktrace:   http://www.uploadmb.com/dw.php?id=1435350484